# Easiest way to drop first (n) item from a list in groovy

Tags: list, groovy

How to drop the first element from a list, **in place** in groovy?

In JS/ruby, it is done with `shift`, `shift!` method.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `tail` method which is specifically there for getting "everything except the first item":

```
groovy:000> [1,2,3,4,5].tail()
===> [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

this in contrast to `head` (head and tail...makes sense) which will give you the first item (same as `first()`):

```
groovy:000> [1,2,3,4,5].head()
===> 1
groovy:000> [1,2,3,4,5].first()
===> 1
```

**correction**: if with "in place" we mean modifying the original list then I think `removeAt` and `remove` are your friends as suggested by a different answer.

`remove` / `removeAt` do not return you the resulting list (they return the removed element) which is unfortunate but seems like they are the only ones actually modifying the list in place.

Though it should be noted that even `remove`/`removeAt` at least for the ArrayList imlementation does do a `System.arraycopy` under the hood which means still copying the data. Granted the copy is done in probably the fastest way possible on the jvm, but still, a copy.

For the constant time removal you might have been looking for you can for example make sure your list is an instance of LinkedList:

```
  def list = [1,2] as LinkedList 
  list.remove(0)
```

at which point the first element is "unlinked" in constant time without any copying of data.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is by slicing:

```
def lst = [1,2,3,4,5]
println lst
lst = lst[1..-1]
println lst
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 4):

how about using pop() method:

```
def list = ["a", false, 2] 
assert list.pop() == 'a' 
assert list == [false, 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `removeAt(0)` or `remove(0)`:

From the [docs for removeAt()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#removeAt):

> Modifies this list by removing the element at the specified position
> in this list. Returns the removed element. Essentially an alias for
> List#remove(int) but with no ambiguity for List<Integer>.

```
def lst = [1, 2, 3]
println lst
lst.removeAt(0) // or lst.remove(0)  
println lst
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 3]
```

Comment: `lst.remove(0)` would also work. `removeAt` is "Essentially an alias for
     * {@link List#remove(int)} but with no ambiguity for List<Integer>"

Answer (score 2):

Also not inline (modifying the list itself), but `drop` is used to drop `n`
(like the subject requested), and ignores whether `n` is greater than the size of the collection (unlike e.g. `tail()`):

```
groovy:000> [1,2,3].drop(1)
===> [2, 3]
groovy:000> [1,2,3].drop(5)
===> []
```